# What does the Docker tutorial mean by "grab a portable Python runtime as an image"?

Tags: python, docker

I am starting the Docker tutorial with the Python app and would like to know what is the meaning of "Python runtime" in this context:

In the past, if you were to start writing a Python app, your first order of business was to install a Python runtime onto your machine. But, that creates a situation where the environment on your machine has to be just so in order for your app to run as expected; ditto for the server that runs your app.

> With Docker, you can just grab a portable **Python runtime** as an image,
>   no installation necessary. Then, your build can include the base
>   Python image right alongside your app code, ensuring that your app,
>   its dependencies, and the runtime, all travel together.

So I guess what it mean is the "Python runtime" is like the configuration of your local Python.

Answer (score 0):

When it says "Python runtime," it just means the Python interpreter in a binary format and its local configuration of package dependencies. Your interpretation is correct.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.